# How to add textfield in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have one tableview which are having one row and one section and the row height of tableview 300, and row have an image which covers whole row. I want to add three textfield and one button; I am adding textfield which are add properly but does not show.

I am adding cellforrowAtIndexPath code is:

```
    companyName = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33, 6, 259, 31)];
    companyName.textColor = [UIColor BlackColor];
    companyName.delegate =self;
    companyName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    companyName.highlighted = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:companyName];
```

Comment: if you found your answer then accept that answer..

Answer (score 5):

you are not adding textfield in cell but adding in UIView.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:companyName];
```

Comment: why the answer is not accepted? it worked for me. the modification i done is                `companyName = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 6, 90, 31)];` and
      `companyName.borderStyle =UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;`